# Losing data in data flow with raw file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

I use Data Flow task with Raw file source and OLE DB Destination (mssql table). I found out that during this load I loose most of the data rows, written in raw file.

I used a Row count transformation to look for a raw file number of rows. And I found out that file raw count is always normal (> 1mln rows), but in target table in some executions there is only 50k - 90k rows, but in some cases data loaded normally (>1 mln rows) and matches file rows count.

In addition, when I get small number of rows and reexecute package, which generate this file and load data in destination table - everything is OK, full number of rows is loaded in destination table.

Data access mode = "Table or view - fast load"
SSIS 2016

Any ideas? I am confused with nonstatic behaviour of this case :(

The Control flow looks like

[image: Control flow. Has a loop in it]

Comment: Yes, that behaviour sounds incorrect. What's intriguing it the run it 2x and it gets the right count. Post up a picture of the Control Flow and the data flows where you create and consume the raw files

Comment: Newcommers can't attch images, so the only chance is via link https://drive.google.com/file/d/12I91snyXGzsoEd0soswKPHoDlhBlQ2lE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: DF "export Sessions_IOS" load data via CData BigQuery connector to raw file. DF "calc rows" save raw file rows count into variable. DF "save row count" writes this variable to log table. If rowcount variable > constant, the DF "load sessions IOS stg" run and load data from raw file to destination table. If not - Execute script task "raise pkg error" throw pkg error to cause its next run attempt in a job.

Comment: Thank you, the picture is quite helpful and I've patched it into the question. The raw file name is built in an expression task on step 2. You then For loop container that is "loop by date" (what are the criteria there?) Should this affect the raw file name if there's more than 1 iteration? The second step in this inner container is where the raw file is created. Could you running into an issue with looping messing with the value in the file? The final step is to delete the raw file, but is a file always created? If it "raises pkg error", does that literally error and thus the file remains?